# How to implement numpy's np.lexsort in torch?

Tags: numpy, pytorch

I've checked that sorting a single column is faster on a GPU with torch than on a CPU with numpy, but I have a large Boolean array (~10^5 x ~10^3), and I need to sort the rows by the first column, breaking ties by the second column, breaking ties by the third, and so on. The numpy function I would use is np.lexsort. How do I do this using torch on a GPU?

By the way, there are more than 64 columns, or else I could turn each row into a single int64 and sort those.

Comment: Using [jax.lexsort](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.lexsort.htm)? Or with [pytorch](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/numpy-lexsort-equivalent-in-pytorch/47850/4).

Comment: Looks like someone created a PyTorch lexsort version here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/numpy-lexsort-equivalent-in-pytorch/47850, and someone else used torch.argsort here to implement it: https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/blob/4722cc0bf0fb8c5c902144f0d72dc55c3335e6d8/pytorch_lightning/metrics/functional/classification.py#L810